# Shouldn't popular cryptographic hash functions encode the length of the input data in the output?

Tags: hash

EDIT2: This discussion was reduced to "are collisions actually harder to create when you add a length constraint?" which is more relevant to the Crypto exchange. I will create a question there and link it when it exists. Thanks for everyone who participated in the discussion

EDIT: The term "Collision attack" in Wikipedia seems to only talk about finding any random collision, I meant to say ["Preimage attack"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preimage_attack).

It would seem like a good idea to me, because it would prevent all collision attacks that require the attacker to modify the length of the data. The attacker would have to find a collision with the exact same length, which is obviously much harder than finding a general collision.

Collision attacks usually require the attacker to modify the length of the data (by appending more blocks to the existing data or something like that), don't they?

The only downside I see to this is that it will require the hash results to be longer (the way I see it only by 2-4 bytes being "The length of the data modulo 2^16-2^32" should be about enough) so not by much.

This of course doesn't have to be part of the hash function itself, it could just be a general security recommendation: "Verify the expected length of the data, not just that it matches the calculated hash, to prevent many forms of collision attacks".

Though I've never heard this recommendation said or mentioned before, even though the way I see it, it makes a lot of sense.

So, in general, I'm asking here: Why is this not a good idea? Should it be encoded in hash functions so it's automatically applied by anyone using those functions, or should it be a general security recommendation that is up to the user of the hash function to implement on his own, separately from the hash function?

Or maybe I'm completely missing something that makes this idea ridiculous?

Comment: The collision attacks against MD5 and SHA1 work only on same-size messages.

Comment: This question might be better suited to [crypto.SE](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/). (This comment posted via [review](https://security.stackexchange.com/review/close/108361).)

Answer (score 6):

You're missing another downside: **it tells the attacker the length of the plaintext.**

In some cases this is considered sensitive information. If I'm brute-forcing passwords, for example, you're telling me that I can skip trying all passwords except those of the specified length. Cool, thanks.

---

> Collision attacks usually require the attacker to modify the length of the data (by appending more blocks to the existing data or something like that), don't they?

I believe you're describing a [length extension attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_extension_attack). The real cryptographers would probably roast me for saying this, but I naively have a possible solution of padding the massage prior to hashing (at which point you can drop the whole length encoding and just use a traditional hash function): _(really, don't go building software based on this, I don't guarantee that it's secure).

```
hash( 0*(256 - (len(msg)%256) ) || msg)
```

Then when the attacker tries to do a length extension attack by concatenating msg2 to the end:

```
hash( 0*(256 - (len(msg||msg2)%256) ) || msg||msg2)
```

they will have a different number of padding 0's, which changes the massage prefix and totally breaks the length extension attack.

*(The more I think about this, the less I want to stand behind the idea. I should probably spend some time googling "length extension attack mitigation" rather than sitting here and speculating)*

Comment: Good point. Can't believe I missed that. Though I still think that padding the result is worth it, since it gives you the great upsides I've mentioned above. Also, you would just have to redefine salting to be more than just appending to the data a fixed length, you just append until the data has a constant length.

Also, many times hash functions are used for signing data which doesn't have a secret length. It would be much more relevant for those uses.

Comment: @Omer What about cases where you don't know in advance how long a file someone's gonna want to hash? Pad every file to 64 gb, just to be safe? If you wanted to store the plaintext length in your DB and have your application check it, that could be ok in the cases you mention, but it's a hard sell that it should be done in the crypto primitive.

Comment: You only have to pad when the length is secret. Can't think of any other use case other than passwords, in which case you can simply pad to 256 bytes or something small like that.

Comment: @Omer Passwords are the only really common case maybe, but I thought about it for a bit, I could certainly construct you a case where the input in really long, variable length, and the length leaks sensitive info.

Comment: @Omer How about this: I want to send you the hash of my Linux distro ISO file so that we can compare that we're using identical files, but I don't want attackers to be able to figure out which version of which distro I'm using. I don't know in advance how large a file I may need to hash because distros keep getting bigger, and the length of the input tells an attacker exactly which file I used by comparing against files available on the standard mirrors. A little contrived as an example maybe, but I think it proves the point that you can't have a hash primitive that leaks plaintext length.

Comment: Fair point. But since it's such a rare use case, maybe hash functions should have different versions: length-hiding and length-encoding. In this case the problem is solved (of course added complexity and what not, but that's not relevant to this discussion).

Comment: don't feed a hash function passwords, you're doing something wrong if you find that happening.

Comment: @dandavis Then what would you like me to feed passwords into?

Comment: a key derivation routine like bcrypt or scrypt or pbkdf; you know, something designed for passwords ;)

Comment: @dandavis Checkmate! pbkdf2 is just just a fancy wrapper for SHA-2. You are literally feeding your password to SHA-2 - many many times. (bcrypt and scrypt are fundamentally different, and better for this reason, but pbkdf2 is still the NIST approved password hashing alg).

Comment: @MikeOunsworth: good game. it's not _just_ feeding it in a loop though, and even if it were, it's designed for that and the construct would still instantly eliminate the utility of a length meta inclusion on the first round...

Comment: @dandavis yeah, point. I guess it was only check, not checkmate.

Comment: hash functions are often used for data anonymization. Leaking the length may in many cases, effectively deanonymize the data.

Comment: Lie Ryan, your comment completely ignored other comments and discussions in this thread. It was already established that this will leak information and I already proposed ways to solve that. It's irrelevant to the discussion by now

Comment: Mike and @Omer But, if you pad all your input to the same length, then haven't you defeated the point of the length encoding anyway? And in the process, you've added an upper limit on input size. Why not just use one of the many existing functions that *don't leak such information in the first place*?

Comment: @8bittree I think you're mixing requirements; the question was about constructing a hash function which guarantees that you can't get a collision between inputs of different lengths. I am not aware of any cryptographic hash functions which make this guarantee. (and I honestly don't remember why I thought padding would solve this problem, I wish I'd put more info in the answer lol)

Comment: @MikeOunsworth (You could still edit the answer.) With the padding, you don't have inputs of different lengths, so avoiding such collisions is irrelevant in such a situation. And of course you're not aware of any hash functions (cryptographic or otherwise) that make such a guarantee a lack of collisions. It's impossible, as per the pigeonhole principle... which, come to think of it, might be an answer to this question. Maybe not. The question does say "more difficult" rather than "impossible".

Comment: @8bittree I'm not sure I follow that logic either; I think by adding padding we were trying to stop [length extension attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_extension_attack), which is what the OP is describing in the question; with padding you can't concatenate to the message without also shortening the padding, which means the attacker needs to modify both the prefix and suffix, so it's no longer a length extension attack.

Comment: I agree with your pigeonhole argument is though \*thumbs up\* in the OP's hashing scheme you would need to fix the number of bits n in the length tag, which means that for for longer inputs than 2^n you would necessarily have collisions (because pigeons).

Comment: @MikeOunsworth The understanding I have is that the hash functions described in the question output the hash, and the length of the input (for the verification purposes mentioned in the question). Traditional hash functions just output the hash. I'm imagining outputs like `abcd 16`; `f0e1 16`; `98ab 16`, compared to simply `abcd`; `f0e1`; `98ab`. I don't understand what the benefit of having the constant `16` tacked on there is. (Also, the pigeonhole argument would apply even if the length tag is unbounded. Once your input is longer than your hash, pigeonhole applies.)

Comment: @8bittree Huh? Why is 16 a constant? He is suggesting `hash("Hello") = abcd..:5` and `hash("Hi there!") = f0e1..:9`. That way even if the hash part of the hash matched for two messages of different length, the length tag wouldn't (up to the width of your length tag, beyond which your pigeonhole argument applies).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81969/discussion-between-8bittree-and-mike-ounsworth).

Answer (score 3):

A cryptographic hash function is designed to have large changes to the output even on small changes to output. By adding some bytes describing the length of the input you change this assumption, since these length bits will only create small changes to the output on small changes to the input.

Apart from that you actually leak important information about the input as [Mike Ounsworth](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/61443/mike-ounsworth) already pointed out. Essentially you tell the attacker not only how long the input will be but also that there is definitely some value that long which results in this hash. This greatly reduces the space the attacker has to brute-force in order to get the same hash result - which in case of passwords is all which is needed since a collusion is not required.

But even in the case where you care about a preimage it is not clear that the bits you add to encode the length would not be more useful instead in extending the strength of the hash itself in order to avoid a preimage attack. While it might help in cases where the input must be shorter than the hash itself and thus preimages are unlikely I think these bits are better used for a longer real hash in case the input is longer then the hash output because same-length preimages are much more likely then.

> The attacker would have to find a collision with the exact same length, which is obviously much harder than finding a general collision.

Is it really that obviously harder? I would agree that it is harder if the input is shorter than the hash since it is a problem of finding preimages at such a small size. But if the input is much larger than the hash (i.e. like with certificates) I doubt that requiring a specific length really adds additional complexity to finding a preimage, unless there is some inherent weakness in how the hash is constructed.

Comment: You answered the exact same thing as Mike. I already replied with more questions. Hash functions are not just for passwords, and for passwords you can always pad (instead of salting with a fixed length, salt with a dynamic length so all passwords have the same length) to keep the length secret.

Comment: @Omer: First, my first paragraph is different to what Mike said. Also, see updated answer.

Comment: So replying to your first paragraph:
So don't call it a hash function, call it hash+size, deviating from the original definition of a hash function is expected, because I'm proposing something new. I want to know why this idea is bad.

Comment: @Omer: I don't think the idea is bad but I think if you make the hash longer anyway then there are better ways to use these additional bits, i.e. use these for a stronger real hash instead  for length information.

Comment: I don't know enough about attacks on hash functions, but for some reason in my memory I remember I read on people causing collisions to some functions by appending specially crafted data to the real data, in a way that doesn't modify the hash. It was only possible to do it by appending data, not by modifying the existing data. Appending will cause a length change, and what I'm proposing will allow a detection of this.

Comment: I think you refer to [length extension attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_extension_attack) but these are not about finding collisions or preimages.

Comment: "But if the input is much larger than the hash (i.e. like with certificates) I doubt that requiring a specific length really adds additional complexity to finding a preimage" - My proposition assumed that it does add additional complexity and that it's obvious. If that's not so obvious, I'm interested to hear from people who know a lot about how hash functions work if a length requirement really makes finding collision harder or not

Comment: @Omer: I agree that it adds complexity but I argue that these length bits would be better used for a real hash to add even more complexity. But you will find probably better experts at crypto.stackexchange.com.

Comment: hash functions are NEVER for passwords, don't be naive...